# Bases of a covector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I want to prove this proposition.

Let $ V $ be a finite dimensional vector space. Given any basis    $ E_1,E_2,...,E_n $ for V, let $ \varepsilon^1,\varepsilon^2,...,\varepsilon^n  \in V^* $ be the covectors defined by

$$
\varepsilon^i(E_j)= \delta_j^i
$$

Then $ \varepsilon^1,\varepsilon^2,...,\varepsilon^n $ is a basis for $ V^* $ and $ dim V^* = dim V$

I have started the proof as follows.

First to prove that the covectors  $ \varepsilon^1,\varepsilon^2,...,\varepsilon^n $ are linearly independent.

If  $ \sum_{i=0}^n r_i\varepsilon^i = 0 $, then

$ r_1\varepsilon^1 + r_2\varepsilon^2 + ... + r_n\varepsilon^n  (E_1) = 0 (E_1)= 0 $

$r_1\varepsilon^1 (E_1)=0 $

$ r_1=0 $

Similarly each $r_i =0 $ which implies the covectors $ \varepsilon^1,\varepsilon^2,...,\varepsilon^n $ are linearly independent .

Now i am struck at proving that $\varepsilon^1,\varepsilon^2,...,\varepsilon^n $ span $ V^* $

The fact that $ dim V = dim V^* $ is not yet known.

Comment: Hint: If $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in V^*$, to show $\omega_1 = \omega_2$ it is enough that $\omega_1(E_i) = \omega_2(E_i)$ for each $i$. Now what happens when you evaluate $c_1\varepsilon_1 + \dots c_n\varepsilon_n$ at $E_i$?

Comment: I cannot write $w_1$ as $ c_1\varepsilon^1 + \dots c_n\varepsilon^n$ until i have proven that $ \varepsilon^1, \varepsilon^2, ... ,\varepsilon^n $ are a basis for $ V^*$

Comment: You can let $\omega_2 = c_1\varepsilon_1 + \dots + c_n\varepsilon_n$ and see what the $c_i$ must be in order to have $\omega_1 = \omega_2$. Then you can verify that these $c_i$ actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last part do
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(x)&=&(f-\sum_{i=1}^nf(E_i)\varepsilon^i)(x),\\
&=&f(x)-\sum_{i=1}^nf(E_i)\varepsilon^i(x),
\end{eqnarray*}
then
for $x=E_k$ you get
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(E_k)&=&f(E_k)-\sum_{i=1}^nf(E_i)\varepsilon^i(E_k),\\
&=&f(E_k)-\sum_{i=1}^nf(E_i)\delta^i_k,\\
&=&f(E_k)-f(E_k),\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}
So $F\equiv0$
and then
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^nf(E_i)\varepsilon^i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that an element $f \in V^*$ is uniquely determined by its values on any basis of $V$.

Now compare $f$ to $\sum_{i = 1}^n f(E_i) \varepsilon^i$ on $E_1,\dots,E_n$ and conclude that these elements of $V^*$ coincide.